# round text in svg in pdf

Tags: svg, pdf-generation, dompdf, svg-font

I am trying to send a SVG file in pdf. The pdf have some rounded/transformed text (company name).

Thing is I get the pdf created but the rounded text does not appear rounded on output PDF but appears straight. I have used DomPDF as well as TCPDF for creating the pdf.
[Here is my SVG](http://iamstellen.pw/greenwonder/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/5555fb6d63f1d-811046726.svg)

Comment: If you are having problems getting the text-on-a-path objects to work with the PDF, you could try the "convert to shapes" option in your vector editor.

Comment: SVG support in dompdf is still in the early stages ([only recently added](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/320#issuecomment-99593458) to the develop branch). Support for text on a path may not yet be available. php-svg-lib provides the functionality, you might try [posting an issue](https://github.com/PhenX/php-svg-lib/issues) to the project.